# VBA Invoice creation in excel through access input form

Tags: vba, ms-access, invoice, creation

I would like to create a form in Access with the button "create invoice". I try to have it do the following:

- Copy the excel "invoice template";
- Move the excel "invoice template" from folder "templates" to folder "invoices";
- Open the "invoices send register" (excel file);
- Open the "customer adresses register" (excel file);
- Rename the invoice template copy as something I that can be entered in a textbox;
- Wait a second;
- Open the newly created excel file to fill in the template in excel.

This is the code I came up with:

```
Private Sub Knop1_Click()

    'Open register with customer adresses
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\Betalingen\Faktuur adressen.xlsx", True, False
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    'Open folder with invoices
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\SFMT\Afleveringsbonnen 2008-heden\2017\Nieuwe systeem (1-3-2017)", vbNormalFocus)

    'Make a copy of the invoice template
    FileCopy "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\SFMT\Afleveringsbon.xlsx", "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\SFMT\Afleveringsbonnen 2008-heden\2017\Nieuwe systeem (1-3-2017)\Nieuwe afleveringsbon.xlsx"

    'Define to what the invoice template should be renamed
    Year = [Tekst3]
    Month = [Tekst6]
    Count = [Tekst9]
    NEWNAME = Year + Month + Count

    'Move and rename the invoice template copy
    Name "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\SFMT\Afleveringsbonnen 2008-heden\2017\Nieuwe systeem (1-3-2017)\Nieuwe afleveringsbon.xlsx" As "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\SFMT\Afleveringsbonnen 2008-heden\2017\Nieuwe systeem (1-3-2017)\P95+$NEWNAME.xlsx"

    'Wait a second to make sure the copiing is completed
    Sleep (1000)

    'Open the moved and renamed invoice template copy
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\SFMT\Afleveringsbonnen 2008-heden\2017\Nieuwe systeem (1-3-2017)\P95+telling", True, False
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be very welcome, this is driving me crazy... I have been trying for hours now.

Comment: And which area of the above code are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated what the actual problem is but I assume that at least part of the problem is with this code:

```
'Open register with customer adresses
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xlApp.Visible = True
 xlApp.Workbooks.Open "\\WDMyCloudEX4\Zakelijk\Documenten\Betalingen\Faktuur adressen.xlsx", True, False
 Set xlApp = Nothing
```

In this code you are creating an Excel application object and opening an Excel workbook through that object and then immediately destroying the application object right after you open the workbook.  So you are effectively opening and then immediately closing the workbook.